# Multiple interfaces for the same struct

Tags: oop, go, struct

I'm learning Go and wondering in some cases if it is considered good/okay/typical (encouraged?) practice in Golang to create several `interface` variations for the same `struct` depending on what the consumer code will be doing with that struct?

I'm questioning this because I have a struct object that is arguably doing too much in my codebase and I want to add some tests and mock only certain usages/consumers of that struct. Say I have,

for a (contrived) example, an Environment struct

```golang
// Environment/env.go

package env

type Environment struct {
  sunny bool,
  fullMoon bool,
  temp float64
  // ...
}

func (e *Environment) IsSunny() bool {
  return e.sunny
}

func (e *Environment) IsFullMoon() bool {
  return e.fullMoon
}

func (e *Environment) GetTemp() float64 {
  return e.temp
}
```

The above struct has properties and methods related to some of the environment conditions (day and night time).

Then there are multiple consumers of this struct, but each `interface` only cares about a subset of the available methods:

```golang
// daytime.go

type DayEnv interface {
  IsSunny() bool
  GetTemp() float64
}

func getDaytime(de DayEnv) {
  sunStatus := getSunStatus(de)
  temp      := getDayTemp(de)

  fmt.Printf("Today is %s and temperature is %s", sunStatus, temp)
}

// func getSunStatus(de DayEnv) string {}
// func getDayTemp(de DayEnv) string {}
```

```golang
// nightTime.go

type NightEnv interface {
  IsFullMoon() bool
  GetTemp() float64
}


func getNighttime(ne NightEnv) {
  moonPhase := getMoonPhase(ne)
  temp      := getNightTemp(ne)

  fmt.Printf("Tonight the moon is %s and temperature is %s", moonPhase, temp)
}

// func getMoonPhase(ne NightEnv) string { }
// func getNightTemp(ne NightEnv) string { }
```

It seems to me while making a new interface that is only concerned with a subset of the struct methods makes things more flexible, it also feels fairly lazy or wrong to have so much (partial) duplication of interfaces and to sprinkle them as need or wherever they are consumed. I realize this example is a bit contrived, but on a larger scale (like many, many consumers), or perhaps one file has `x` interfaces for the same struct... is there anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: In my opinion, your codes are showing what *"Duck typing"* is, and I think that's one of the core concepts of Go.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this approach, and Go standard library uses it often. For instance, there are many structs that implement a combination of io.Reader, io.Writer, io.Closer, and io.Seeker. The users of those structs specify what type of interface they need and use that.

Comment: To add to that, having small 1-2 method interfaces improves the readability of your program by making it more explicit what certain functions are expecting. Writing mocks also becomes much easier since you don't need to mock out the entire interface for a function only expecting to use one method from the interface.

Comment: Additionally, the practice of using small interfaces makes it easy to work with down the road. If you have a single interface that is likely to grow in the future, you're better off taking the time to split it up now instead of waiting until it is cumbersome to work with and then having to do refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

interface is the essential part of golang to implement "Polymorphism". Not only did you do it right, you also found the essence of interface.